# Escape strings when creating a dynamic update statement

Tags: string, t-sql, quotes

I have a stored procedure that is generating a string that it will call EXECUTE() on. The string contains an UPDATE statement. However, the columns and values that it is executing are not known beforehand. These are coming into the stored procedure through an XML string. I then use XML queries to get the data out and into a temporary table.

This is not sanitizing the data.

```
DECLARE @TBL_FLD TABLE (
    TBL         VARCHAR(MAX),
    COL         VARCHAR(MAX),
    VAL         VARCHAR(MAX)
);

-- Fill @TBL_FLD via xml parsing (omitted for brevity)

DECLARE TBL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT distinct (TBL) FROM @TBL_FLD;

OPEN TBL_CURSOR;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_CURSOR INTO @TABLE_NAME
    IF ( @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 )
        BREAK

    SET @SETTING_STR = '';
    SELECT @SETTING_STR = STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + COL + ' = ''' + VAL + '''' FROM @TBL_FLD WHERE TBL = @TABLE_NAME FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '');

    SET @SQL_QUERY += 'UPDATE ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' SET ' + @SETTING_STR + ' WHERE KEY = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @KEY_VAL) + '; ';

END
CLOSE TBL_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE TBL_CURSOR

EXECUTE (@SQL_QUERY);
```

I trust the COL field of @TBL_FLD, but the VAL will have come from a user. Which leaves a massive security hole since I am just concatenating the data together. There has to be a better way.

Since there are an unknown number of columns, I can't easily create parameters for the statement so that the data is cleaned up. If worst comes to worst, I can do it, (see the answer to [Dynamically Create Update SQL In Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110141/dynamically-create-update-sql-in-stored-procedure)) but it will be uglier than I would like.

Is there a function, or method, to sanitize the data, before I blindly add it to the statement? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that just doubling single quotes with a `REPLACE` on VAL would fix any issues since an attacker would not be able to exit the "string scope" to execute arbitrary code :

```
SELECT @SETTING_STR = STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + COL + ' = ''' + REPLACE(VAL, '''', '''''') + '''' FROM @TBL_FLD WHERE TBL = @TABLE_NAME FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 2, '');
```

I don't remember a built-in T-SQL function that does the same thing

Comment: Wow. It really is that simple. Thanks.